# CSS - Globally select all pseudo-classes (::before, ::after, etc)

Tags: css, class, select, global

How would I be able to select all of those classes in once?

I've tried the following, but doesn't seem to work:

```
.myClass *::before { background: red !important; }
.myClass *:before  { background: red !important; }
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Basically i'm trying to select ALL occurrences in the given selector (in this case 'myClass'), so I can GLOBALLY rewrite a rule, without having to have multiple lines and / or multiple blocks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `content` attribute for `:before` to work. So if you have not set up it properly anywhere else, than your code will not work (missing `content` attribute)

```css
.myClass {
  counter-reset: section;
}
:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section)')';
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
.myClass :before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm familiar with setting the **'content'** attribute, in order to make the ::before / ::after class work. But this was not the answer i'm looking for. Basically i'm trying to select ALL occurrences in the given selector (in this case **'myClass'**), so I can GLOBALLY rewrite a rule, without having to have multiple lines and / or multiple blocks.

Comment: @Bilal075_ So `.myClass :before` will select all `:before` that has parent `.myClass`. Am I missing something? Can you provide SO Snippet with your issue?

Comment: @Bilal075_ Check updated answer if it's what you want.

Comment: .myClass *::before, should be readen like this: .myClass * (which selects ALL elements in **'myClass'**), and once that's done, I want to select the **::before** class of all those selected elements.

Comment: @Bilal075_ `.myClass *:before` is same as `.myClass :before`